# Why does nobody ever seem to write `delete &someObj`?

Tags: c++

Ok, this may seem ridiculous but I so often see code where dynamically allocated memory deleted using a reference looks like this:

```
Obj* ptr = &someObj;
delete ptr;
```

instead of what seems like the logical alternative:

```
delete &someObj;
```

Is there any particular safety reason behind this, or is it just a style thing?

Comment: Thankfully you don't have to use `new`/`delete` anymore thanks to smart pointers.

Comment: Because it would be totally and utterly incorrect 99.99% of the time, unless you *knew* that the object had been dynamically allocated, which `&` certainly doesn't tell you.

Comment: do you have an online example where you have seen this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no added safety. It was a style choice of the person that wrote the quoted code.

PS. It is (or should be) extremely rare to delete dynamically allocated memory through a reference. It is a very common convention to store the addresses of dynamic objects in pointers. These days it should be rare to delete any memory manually at all, since the task is conventionally delegated to smart pointers.

Comment: I do typically try to use smart pointers but the engine i'm using was written for our uni projects, where old and new code is sort of mushed together. Anyway, Thank you for the answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if you allocate memory dynamically, then you receive a pointer, not the value itself.

```
int* a = new int;
```

Then you've got to call delete and pass the pointer:

```
delete a;
```

If you try to assign in to a variable like that `int b = *a;` then `b` is **not** dynamically allocated. So you can not write `delete &b;` because `b` is allocated on stack and will be automatically cleaned up when it goes out of scope. If you assign it to a reference like `int& c = *a;` then you are able to write `delete &c;` but that's a bad error-prone style, because you don't have any guarantee that the memory referenced by `c` is dynamically allocated.

Comment: Though I do think it's error prone, it's not really because "you don't have any guarantee that the memory referenced by c is dynamically allocated." as you can say the exact same thing if it were just a pointer.